# Can't get Unity 3D to work in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity

I recently upgraded to 11.10 on my Lenovo ThinkPad T520, and I'm not able to load Unity 3D (I'm not selecting 2D at login menu either).

```
me@mycomp:~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
ubuntu-2d
```

I ran the unity support test below as well.

```
me@mycomp:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error: unable to create the OpenGL context
```

And it looks like I only have one graphics card:

```
me@mycomp:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Also, Ubuntu lists nothing under the "Additional Drivers" window.

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I'm somewhat of a noob.  Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

Here is the output of lshw -C display

```
me@mycomp:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:f0000000-f03fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it has an eg. Intel HD 3000 chipset or an integrated graphics chipset, maybe this PPA can be of help: https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers (to be used with care).

Take a look on the xorg-edgers PPA, add it `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/drivers-only` (this is the relatively safe one) and do an `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`, maybe it can already update your Intel xorg driver.

Else you can try the unsafe one (you'll find it on the PPA Launchpad link i mentioned above).

Remember using the edgers PPA can break your graphics.

If you have any issues - you should use `ppa-purge` to remove the PPA.

Comment: Thank you, @fossfreedom, for the supplementary warning I neglected!